# c++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i'm not sure if what im talking about is an operator overloading question.
is it possible to overload keywords in C++??
for example : i need to write loopOver(i=0; ;i++) instead of for(i=0;;i++) ?? is that possible in C++

and i need to have something like 2 addTo 2  instead of 2 + 2

please help 
thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a macro
#define loopOver for
#define addTo +

Comment: Do you have a hidden reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: Why do you *"need to write"* this? With a background you might get more helpful answers.

Comment: its just a homework  . :D , no hidden reason or something .

Comment: What a bad homework assignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that with operator overloading (you can't change the names of the operators, only how they work).

However, evil as it is, if you don't want to change the way they work (just the names), you would be able to achieve things like this using macros:

```
#define loopOver for
#define addTo +
```

(Use macros with extreme care though - if used incorrectly they can cause hideous problems)

Comment: I upvoted this because it's the correct answer, but only after overcoming my reflexive urge to downvote any post which contains code that re-#defines the `for` keyword.

Comment: I agree. This is the answer to the OP, not the answer to the question "should I actually do this?", to which the answer is an emphatic "no!".

Comment: Best to do this in a public header, to increase the fun for others using your library :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use #define directive

```
#define loopOver for
#define addTo +
```

But this is just bad!

And no - this is no operator overloading question. Here You have some informations: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading